# How do I change the name and color of a potion?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know this is how you get a nausea potion:

```
/give @p minecraft:potion 1 0 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:9,Duration:100}]}
```

but how do I change it so its name it different or so that the potions color is different?

Answer (score 1):

The `Name` tag, held within the `display` compound, specifies the item's name.

As of 1.11, all potion items must have a proper `Potion` string tag in order for its color to be modifiable. You can use a value of "minecraft:water" to not add any extra effects to it, and it will be colored based solely on color mixing from `CustomPotionEffects`:

```
/give @p minecraft:potion 1 0 {Potion:"minecraft:water",CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:9,Duration:100}],display:{Name:"Custom Name"}}
```

If you want to specify a color directly, you can use the `CustomPotionColor` integer tag, which takes a decimal color value (example color picker [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/hexadecimal-decimal-colors.html)). For example, the following gives a white-colored potion:

```
/give @p minecraft:potion 1 0 {Potion:"minecraft:water",CustomPotionColor:16777215,CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:9,Duration:100}],display:{Name:"Custom Name"}}
```

Comment: i tried using that and the potion just keeps coming out purple

Comment: @CameronJosephson What version are you using? `CustomPotionColor` is 1.11+ only. You cannot strictly specify a custom potion color prior to 1.11 and must instead rely on color mixing.

Comment: okay yeah yeah i was using 1.10 but i can switch it to 1.11 so thanks